# Cannot open page after deployment of JSF application

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2, tomcat8

I'm working on very simple JSF application which is not working on Tomcat8 server. See the attached file.

[zip file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rqm46vjvatwqg0j/Web_site.zip?dl=0)

**faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">

</faces-config>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    <display-name>jsflab</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

**POM.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.qussay</groupId>
    <artifactId>Web_site</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Web_site</name>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

When I open the web page `http://x.x.x.x:8080/Web_site/index.jsf` I see `HTTP Status 404`

Can you help me to fix this issue?

Comment: I assume you checked the server log and found either errors there or a message about a succesful deployment

Comment: I see only `Web_site-1.0.war has finished in 808 ms` There are no errors.

Comment: How do you run the server? With the startup script? maven? within Eclipse?

Comment: I just deployed the war package into webapps while the server was running

Comment: Try renaming index.jsf to index.xhtml.
And can you see a Web_site/ directory in webapps?

Comment: No, there is still no change